# Como reduzir o espaçamento entre caracteres impressos com \t no C++?

Tags: c++, formatação

Queria colocar as colunas mais próximas para que não aconteça como na figura 2.

```
int i,j,elemento;

for(i=0; i<elemento; i++){
    for(j=-elemento; j<=elemento; j++){
        if(i >= abs(j)) {
            cout<<"\t"<<abs(j)+1;

        }
        else{
            cout<<"\t";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

[image: espaçado]
[image: outro exemplo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não usando o `\t`. Use espaços e controle quantos você quer, 1 ou 2 parece ser adequado. A tabulação depende do mecanismo de console que está usando, mas o normal é, ou era, 8.

Note que a tabulação de fato é flexível, ele pula a cada 8 caracteres, então se o que está escrito tem 1 caractere e 7 espaços, se tem 3 caracteres terão 5 espaços até chegar no chamado *tab stop*. Com espaços você não tem isto, mas se pode garantir que todos os escritos possuem 1 caractere fica fácil.

Se tivesse uma situação em que a quantidade de caracteres fosse variável aí precisaria formatar o texto para ter sempre a mesma quantidade, mesmo que tivesse que colocar espaços à direita dele para encher toda área prevista. Isto pode ser feito com formatação padrão ou através de um *padding* de *string* manual.